# Controlling for baseline imbalance

Tags: reliability, ancova, growth-model

I have a quick question about growth curve modelling and baseline imbalance: do growth curve models control for baseline imbalance and if so, do they control for imbalance in a reliable way, i.e., compatible with ANCOVA?

Comment: Is this from a randomized trial? Why is there baseline imbalance?

Answer (score 1):

The oldest form of growth curve modeling is generalized least squares which assumes multivariate normality.  Yes it can handle baseline covariates just as ANCOVA does [ANCOVA is a special case of generalized least squares], and if you measure the right variables and model them properly (e.g., allowing for nonlinearities) you will get an adequate adjustment for baseline imbalance in a nonrandomized study.